# How can I parse a std::string (YYYY-MM-DD) into a COleDateTime object?

Tags: c++, parsing, visual-c++, mfc, coledatetime

I have a `COleDateTime` object and I want to parse a date string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

The string variable, for example, is:

```
std::string strDate = "2022-07-04";
```

`COleDateTime` allows me to use `ParseDateTime` to parse a string, but I see no way to tell it what format the components of the date string are. In C# I can do such with `DateTime.Parse...`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class?view=msvc-170#format maybe?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No - that is for formatting the date AS a string. My question is about PARSING a string into a date.

Comment: Why not using sscanf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the suggestion by @xMRi in the comments I have decided to use:

```
CString strDutyMeetingDate = CString(tinyxml2::attribute_value(pDutyWeek, "Date").c_str());
int iDay{}, iMonth{}, iYear{};
if(_stscanf_s(strDutyMeetingDate, L"%d-%d-%d", &iYear, &iMonth, &iDay) == 3)
{
    const auto datDutyMeetingDate = COleDateTime(iYear, iMonth, iDay, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just a simple formatted input.

```
std::stringstream ss(strDate);
int year, month, day;
char dash;
ss >> year >> dash >> month >> dash >> day;
COleDateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

`COleDateTime::ParseDateTime` uses default parameter `LANG_USER_DEFAULT`, it can be called as

```
COleDateTime dt;
dt.ParseDateTime("2022-07-04");
```

Or

```
dt.ParseDateTime("2022-07-04", VAR_DATEVALUEONLY, LANG_USER_DEFAULT);
```

`"2022-07-04"` uses long date format so it should be safe, because it is clear that the year is at the start, and month is expected to be in the middle. I believe any LCID should return `2022-July-4th` (I am 60% sure!)

If the date string was short, it could get confused with `MM/DD/YY` format, but that's not a problem here.

To make the `lcid` manually, see the English-US example below, although it should not be necessary in this case.

```
LCID lcid = MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US), SORT_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't doubt you when you say I can just use the string verbatim. But, since the application supports 50+ languages, and you are only 60% sure ... I have left it as I coded it.